# Как выводить через console.log в последнюю строку?

Tags: javascript

Как продолжать выводить в консоль, при вызове `console.log()`, не с новой строки каждый раз, а продолжить вывод текста в текущую строку?

Comment: писать данные в переменную и в конце выводить ее в консоль?

Comment: [это невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627657/2881286)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно console.log() всегда вставляет в конец символ конца строки и изменить это не представляется возможным.

Проблему в данном случае целиком и полностью решает следующий метод: process.stdout.write()

Comment: если указываешь метод специфичный для определенной среды выполнения, лучше указать где он будет работать. Например в браузере нет `process`

Answer (score 2):

Делается это просто. Вот пример:

```js
var cars = {
a184bx154:'Хонда инспаер',
b397ax54:'Лада калина',
x888xx77:'Ешка',
o777oo140:'Беха X5'
};
var index = 0;
var log = '';
for(var key in cars)
{
index++;
log+='№'+index+') машина '+cars[key]+' с номером '+key+';'
}
console.log(log);
```

Нужно писать в переменную а в конце уже использовать console.log для вывода того что записали

Comment: Мне этот способ не подходит. В моём случае в строку нужно добавлять данные в разное время.

Comment: Имеется в виду не строка - переменная, а строка консоли.

Comment: @AND Вы не можете контролировать запись в консоли после вывода.

Comment: Ладно, пусть я не могу контролировать запись в консоли после её вывода, но хотя бы можно заставить consol.log() выводить строку без символа перевода строки в конце?

Comment: @AND оно так не работает. https://habrahabr.ru/post/114483/ очень хорошая статья по console, может она добавит понимания, что из себя представляет консоль в js